# I cannot export data in some formats using the Blazegraph web interface

Tags: blazegraph

I am trying to export all the data in one namespace from my blazegraph instance via the web interface.

After I run a query and get some results I hit the "Export" button. The export function gives me the option of exporting as csv, json and xml. But all the RDF options such as  RDF/XML, Turtle etc are greyed out.
How can I access those export options on the web interface?

I am running version 2.1.5 of Blazegraph

Comment: I guess these options are available for `CONSTRUCT` queries only.

Comment: You are right! Thanks so much for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can export all data in the format you desire by using a `CONSTRUCT` query in a POST request like this:

```
curl --X POST \
  --url 'https://{host}/bigdata/namespace/{namespace}/sparql' \
  --data-urlencode 'query=CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } where { ?s ?p ?o }' \
  --header 'Accept: application/x-turtle' > outputfile.ttl
```